# Aribitrary location match for a Dojo ComboBox

Tags: dojo

When ever you type anything in Dojo's ComboBox you get a list of possibilities based on the options that it has set but the matching only happens at the beginning of the string. I was wondering if there is a way to match any position in the option string.

For example if you options are: "Windows", "Linux", "OSX", "AIX", "Solaris" and you type "in" then the options that would show up are "Windows" and "Linux"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change [queryExpr](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dijit.form.ComboBoxMixin.queryExpr) attribute

Comment: This works but the field gets updated with the first option. Si if I wanted to write "inux" I wouldn't be able because the combo box would have updated to "Windows"